# How to reclaim the value-added tax when buying something on eBay?

Tags: taxes, vat, germany, switzerland, ebay

I want to buy a [digital graphics pad/touchscreen](http://www.ebay.ch/itm/SMART-SYMPODIUM-ID370-INTERACTIVE-TOUCH-PEN-DISPLAY-17-034-LCD-/131369053753?hash=item1e9634ae39&quantity=1&autorefresh=true) on eBay for technical drawings.

Because the article's seller is based in Germany, and I live in Switzerland, and because the article is worth more than CHF 200, it will need to be declared on customs, and duty paid.

Which means I have to pay 8% VAT (for Switzerland). 
On the bright side, that means I should get 19% VAT back (from Germany). 
However, the eBay sell-price states that it includes VAT.

How do I have to procede with buying so that I can successfully reclaim the 19% in the end ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reclaim the German VAT (unless you travel to Germany to collect the item), but the German vendor should not be charging VAT on sales of goods that will be exported from the EU. You need to get the vendor to quote and charge you a VAT-free price.

Comment: He did - after asking.